# Linq to scan an assembly for a method with a particular attribute and attribute property

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I'm attempting to write a linq statement that will scan the entire executing assembly for a method that has a particular attribute and a particular attribute property value.

This is my attribute...

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ScenarioSetup : Attribute
{
    public string ScenarioTitle { get; set; }

    public bool ActiveForBuild { get; set; }
}
```

And this is an example of a method that uses it....

```
[ScenarioSetup(ScenarioTitle = "R/S/T [Assessor Management] ASM.08 - Activate Assessor", ActiveForBuild = true)]
public void CreateInactiveAssessor()
{
    var assessor = ApiHelper.PostRequest(AssessorFactory.CreateAssessorApi("Woodwork"), Client, false);

    AddStateItem(assessor, StateItemTag.AssessorEntity);
}
```

So using the example above, I would like to use reflection to find the method with the `[ScenarioSetup]`  attribute, then check whether that attributes `ScenarioTitle` equals a certain value (in this case 'R/S/T [Assessor Management] ASM.08 - Activate Assessor')

This is what I have so far...

```
var methodz = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods())
            .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ScenarioSetup), false).Length > 0);
```

I then get lost trying to do the `ScenarioTitle` check.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can treat the result of `GetCustomAttributes` as a collection of `ScenarioSetup`, then you can check if any of their titles match: `m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ScenarioSetup), false).OfType<ScenarioSetup>().Where(ss => ss.ScenarioTitle == "R/S/T [Assessor Management] ASM.08 - Activate Assessor")`  EDIT: By the way, feel free to split the LINQ query into two or more queries/steps or even use a `foreach` loop. No _need_ to have it all in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
var methodz = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                      .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods())
                      .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ScenarioSetupAttribute), false)
                      .Cast<ScenarioSetupAttribute>().Where(a=>a.ScenarioTitle=="R/S/T [Assessor Management] ASM.08 - Activate Assessor").Length > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is:

`

```
var methods = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
.GetTypes()
.SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods())
.Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes<ScenarioSetupAttribute>().Any())
.Where(x=>x.GetCustomAttribute<ScenarioSetupAttribute>().ScenarioTitle=="R/S/T [Assessor Management] ASM.08 - Activate Assessor");`
```